# How can I dynamically display some contents of an Electron BrowserWindow in a web browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, server, electron

**EDIT: I fixed my issue. I was using the wrong `BrowserWindow` to send the 'receive-chunk' ipc message and I also had to create two separate scripts for the `webReader.html` file, one to run in the Electron context and one to run in the browser.**

Inside my main BrowserWindow in my Electron app, there is a `<textarea />`. I want to display the contents of this element in an actual web browser window on localhost. The text in the web browser needs to continuously update as the user types more text into the `<textarea />`. I am trying to use an HTTP server + WebSocket to achieve this but I don't understand how to display my Electron HTML page in the browser.

Whenever the user types a new word, I send the word to the main process, which then sends it to the secondary renderer process via this handler:

```
ipcMain.on('send-chunk', async (_event, data) => {
    console.log('data from main renderer:', data)
    mainWindow.webContents.send('receive-chunk', data)
  })
```

The secondary renderer process looks like this:

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron')
const WebSocket = require('ws')

const webReaderDisplay = document.getElementById('web-reader-display')
const webReaderContents = []

const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080')

ws.onopen = function (event) {
  console.log('WebSocket connection opened:', event)
}

ws.onmessage = function (event) {
  console.log('renderer received: %s', event.data)
  webReaderContents.push(event.data)
  webReaderDisplay.textContent = webReaderContents.join(' ')
}

ws.onerror = function (event) {
  console.error('WebSocket error observed:', event)
}

ws.onclose = function (event) {
  console.log('WebSocket connection closed:', event)
}

ipcRenderer.on('receive-chunk', (_event, data) => {
  ws.send(data)
})
```

Here is the server code:

```
const Server = require('http')
const { WebSocketServer } = require('ws')

const server = Server.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200)
  res.end('hello world')
})

const wss = new WebSocketServer({ server })

wss.on('connection', ws => {
  console.log('Client connected')

  ws.on('message', message => {
    console.log('received: %s', message)
  })

  ws.on('close', () => {
    console.log('Client disconnected')
  })
})

server.listen(8080)
```

And finally here is the HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="../dist/output.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="text-center text-system-platinum bg-system-gray-dark">
      <h3>Live Transcript</h3>
    </header>
    <section class="bg-system-platinum">
      <div class="border-system-gray-dark indent-4">
        <p class="text-system-gray-dark" id="web-reader-display">
          Text will appear here
        </p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <script src="webReaderRenderer.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```